# React - Setting a state after Api Requset Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set a state to the data i get from an API Request and then pass it as props to other component, but i get Error, the setState is not working

```
const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://localhost:44368/api/parts/view').then(res => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      let resData = res.data;
      setData(resData);
      console.log(Data);
    });

  }, []);

return (
    <div>
      <DrawerCMP>
        <TableTitle title='Part' />
        {isLoading ? <Spinner /> : <DataTable data={Data} />}
      </DrawerCMP>
    </div>
  );
```

console.log(Data) is returning an empty array []

the error i get

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Comment: maybe check for if the array is empty `Data.length > 0 ? <DataTable data={Data} /> : "No Data"` also dont forget to add `[ ]` at the end of `useEffect` it will cause infinite loop thing

Comment: @NaolChala: Not necessarily an infinite loop. Not providing 2nd argument (the dependencies) to `useEffect` means it will run that effect every time the state changes.

Comment: yeah, because you're changing the state in `useEffect` function it will run it again then changes the state and runs it again, and continues, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im pretty sure that if you set the loading state after you've set the data it should work fine. Because what happens when you get a response is

- first you set loading to false, meaning the DataTable should render on the screen before data is even set.

Answer (score 1):

`setLoading` should be set to false *after* you've updated the data state.

More importantly your code is very confusing because it appears that you're trying return JSX markup from the `useEffect` hook which is not how it works.

```
function Component() {

  const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://localhost:44368/api/parts/view').then(res => {
      let resData = res.data;
      setData(resData);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <DrawerCMP>
        <TableTitle title='Part' />
        {isLoading ? <Spinner /> : <DataTable data={Data} />}
      </DrawerCMP>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: Just a copying mistake